# why this face is always black?

Tags: texturing, uv, faces

I unwrapped the whole mesh, but one face is always black, I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> but there is no change.

in the 2d editor "View > UV Local View" isn't selected

you can get the blend here : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37300

[image: black face in mesh without texture]

Comment: Are you sure nothing is overlapping this particular face.
I would suggest for you to unwrap this separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black face's normal is flipped so you have to recalculate the normals (Toggle into Edit Mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> > Select All <kbd>A</kbd> > Recalculate Normals <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
and also move the light source to see that the texture is there and it's just bad lighting causing the black face.

[image]

Comment: damn! the light... I din't check that! thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why the face can be black.

I think we should take a look at what material is assigned to that face. That is not visible in your screen shot. Different faces can have different materials.

To assign a material to all faces, select all while in edit mode. While still in edit mode, go to material tab, select desired material, and click "assign" button

Comment: I tried that before posting. I added a link to the blend.

Comment: Ah I see the problem was the normal of that face. I was going to suggest that first, but I figured you would have seen that when you flipped normals back and forth. Always try the "recalculate outside" method of calculating normals first. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to check your **Vertex Color layer**.

[image] [image]

While working in Textured shading mode with the Blender Render engine, vertex color layer is overlayed on the texture with a sort of "multiply" blending mode. So if one of your faces is panted with black (rgb=[0,0,0]), its vertex color will completely overwhelm the face texture.

[image]

If you don't want vertex color to be shown while working with texture, but you don't want to lose that vertex color layer, you can **create a new, all white, vertex color layer** and set it as active.

[image]

Comment: I don't use vertex color, you can check yourself in the .blend